# Question about diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Here is an assignment problem:

$f:\mathbb{S}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is smooth and surjective. Prove $\exists$ open subset $ U $ of $\mathbb{S}^2$, such that $f|_U$ is a diffeomorphism.

I've tried to relate it to covering maps but failed.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Can we use [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard's_theorem)?

Comment: Start with Sard's Theorem, using the fact that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Sure. Could you tell me how to use Sard to prove this?

Comment: Sard's theorem implies that there exists $p\in\mathbb S^2$, such that $f(p)\in\mathbb S^2$ is a regular value of $f$. It follows that $Df(p)$ is invertible, so you can apply inverse function theorem around $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sard's Theorem. It gives a regular value of $f$, and since $f$ is surjective, this means that the regular value isn't vacuous (i.e. it's not just something not in the image of $f$). This gives us a point at which the derivative of $f$ is an isomorphism. Then hit it with the Inverse Function Theorem to get your diffeomorphism.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem